# AngularJs ng-options (ke,value) ng-model="selected" doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my Html:

```
<select ng-options="value.name for (key, value) in countries track by key" ng-model="selected" >
</select>
```

This is the object im trying to work on:

```
$scope.countries = {
    "AFG":{"name":"Afghanistan"},
    "ALB":{"name":"Albania"}
};
$scope.countriesKeys = Object.keys($scope.countries);
$scope.selected = ????;
```

My problem is that I can't manage to make the `ng-model` selected to work, the object's structure makes it difficult.. (can't change the object).

In the end my purpose is to make the `<select>` with a first selected option `"ALB":{"name":"Albania"}` and make it dynamic so when I press other options to make `$scope.selected` change.

Comment: Thanks that actually helped, 
but $scope.selected is now 
selected = Object {name: "Afghanistan"} and i would like the have the key too ( "AFG")

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following line:

```
$scope.selected={"name":"Albania"}
```

Comment: Hi, 
first of all i removed the "item as ..." and dynamically my $scope.selected is now selected=Object {name: "Afghanistan"} 
and i would like to have the Key too (AFG) it is really important

Comment: <option value="?" selected="selected"></option> (DOM output) 
(using your way) the selected still doesnt work

Comment: use "key for (key, value) in countries track by key"
and set $scope.selected='AFG'

Comment: but then in my html Output my options dont have the the value

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

//controller
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = {
        "AFG":{"name":"Afghanistan"},
        "ALB":{"name":"Albania"}};
        $scope.countriesKeys=Object.keys($scope.countries);
        $scope.selected="ALB";
  
        $scope.changeSelected = function(newSelected){
            $scope.selected=newSelected;
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="div1" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{selected}}
    <select ng-options="key as value.name for (key, value) in countries" ng-change="changeSelected(selected)"  ng-model="selected"></select>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var getKeyByValue = function( value,array1 ) {
for( var prop in array1 ) {
    if( array1.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
         if( array1[ prop ] === value )
             return prop;
    }
}
```

I have added this function to my controller

```
getKeyByValue($scope.selected,$scope.countries)
```

now I have both value and key from the `<option>` 
Thank for every one who tried to help 
 mostly my problem was that I added "item as value.name..."